# How to define a protocol that specializes a generic protocol, so that it can be used in type declarations?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm an Android developer learning iOS development and I'm facing this issue that is trivial with Kotlin/Java interfaces, but I can't get through it with Swift protocols.

Say we have this protocol:

```swift
protocol ValueStore {
  associatedtype Value
  var value: Value? { get set }
}
```

In Kotlin/Java, if I want to use a generic abstraction to define a variable type, I just use a generic interface with type parameter:

```
val stringStore: ValueStore<String>
```

Since this is not possible in Swift, I tried to create a specialized sub-protocol that defines the associated type:

```swift
protocol StringStore: ValueStore where Value == String { }
```

with the intent to use the latter like this:

```swift
let stringStore: StringStore
```

The above declaration is what I'm trying to achieve. Yet the compiler tells me `Protocol 'StringStore' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`.

Although in type declarations I can use a specialized generic concrete implementation, i.e. `UserDefaultsValueStore<String>`, this is against the dependency inversion principle.

Is it possible to specialize a protocol with associated type and still maintaining the level of abstraction?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly... Try this:

```
protocol ValueStoreType {
  associatedtype Value
  var value: Value? { get set }
}

struct ValueStore<T>: ValueStoreType {
  var value: T?
}
```

Then you will be able to do:

```
var stringStore: ValueStore<String>
```

Comment: This way I'd be declaring a concrete implementation type instead of an abstract type. which takes away the layer of abstraction; this again seems to break the D.I.P. I'm afraid that the concept I'd like to achieve is not supported at language level, I wonder if there's a workaround technique.